# Объединение двух запросов в один.

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть два запроса:

```
$messfull=@mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `message` WHERE `id`='$mid' ")); //запрос в таблицу message, где ищется сообщение с id==$mid
            $messfrom=@mysql_fetch_array(@mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`='{$messfull['fromu']}' ")); //Запрос в таблицу с юзерами, где вытаскивается вся информация о юзере с id=$messfull['fromu'] "от кого пришло сообщение".
```

Подскажите, как объединить эти два запроса в один.
Ps. Если можно, ещё вытаскивать из таблицы users не всю информацию о юзере, а только столбцы name, lname, avatar, online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT name, lname, avatar, online FROM message, users WHERE message.id='$mid' AND users.id=message.fromu
```

Comment: Суть в том, что переменная $messfull['fromu'] появляется после первого запроса

Comment: Здесь все это делается в нужном порядке. Попробуй.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT m.*, u.name AS userName, u.lname AS userLname, u.avatar AS userAvatar, u.online AS userOnline FROM message AS m INNER JOIN users AS u ON m.fromu = u.id AND m.id='{$mid}'";

$r = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$result = Array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r)) {

   $result[] = $row;

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `message`
LEFT JOIN `users` ON (`users`.`id` = `message`.`fromu`)
WHERE `message`.`id`='$mid'
```